# How to use an API to set the columnVisibilityModel in MUI DataGrid Pro

Tags: reactjs, json, material-ui, datagrid

Looking at the columnVisibilityModel in Mui, it seems to just be a JSON object.

I am calling an API that sets the JSON object, but if I pass it to the grid, I get an error.

Example object:

```
{
  id: false,
  name: true,
  middle: false
}
```

if I set columnVisibilityModel like this it works:

```
columnVisibilityModel: {
  id: false,
  name: true,
  middle: false
}
```

but if I have a variable set (i.e. visibleColumns) and try this, it fails:

`columnVisibilityModel: visibleColumns`

I have tried using the apiRef examples with no luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are setting `visibleColumns` like this:

   ```js
   const [visibleColumns, setVisibleColumns] =
     React.useState<GridColumnVisibilityModel>({});
   ```

   or:

   ```js
   const defaultVisibleColumns = {
     id: false,
     name: false,
     middle: false,
   };
   const [visibleColumns, setVisibleColumns] =
     React.useState<GridColumnVisibilityModel>(defaultVisibleColumns);
   ```
2. Double check your API is indeed returning a JSON object:

   ```js
   try {
     const visibleColumns = {
       id: false,
       name: true,
       middle: false
     };
     // or const visibleColumns = await client.query(query) if querying from the DB
     res.status(200).json(visibleColumns);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
     res.status(500).json("Error fetching visible columns");
   }
   ```

Comment: Teresa Lin I have tried that solution, but I get an import error:
```Attempted import error: 'GridColumnVisibilityModel' is not exported from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro' (imported as 'GridColumnVisibilityModel').```

Comment: Actually, I may just need to update my package, currenly using 5.17.18...

Comment: @Weizguy Yeah, that error means `GridColumnVisibilityModel` does not exist in your package version.

Comment: I have upgraded to v6.16.1 and I still get the same import error...

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run `npm install` again

Comment: Yes, tried that with no luck, I may have to open a ticket with them since I am paying for the pro version.